# How to get ScrollTop in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

My script has stopped working since chrome has updated

```
$('.button').click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 600}, 1000);
});
```

This used to scroll down on click but now it does nothing. console log shows `body.scrollTop is deprecated in strict mode. Please use 'documentElement.scrollTop' if in strict mode and 'body.scrollTop' only if in quirks mode.`

I've tried

```
$(document.documentElement).animate(....);   //Nothing happens
$(document.documentElement.body).animate(....); //
```

Comment: Maybe you can update your jQuery to latest version. I tried this code on my Chrome and it works fine.

Comment: I have linked to google hosted jquery ver 2.0.3 :|

Comment: Can you paste your Chrome version and DOCTYPE?

Comment: Chrome Version 32.0.1700.76 m & <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: I've tried it with all the same versions and it is fine.

Comment: Yeah I forgot to update here, CSS was causing it not to work, I reverted to an old git version to find it worked, copied all the html across to modern version to find it didnt work so i disabled styles and it worked agian. HTML{overflowX:hidden} was the problem i think